# CodeIgniter: How to join two table columns and use like active record for querying both?

Tags: codeigniter, search, activerecord

```
public function search($query, $limit) {
    // output
    $output = "";
    // query
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("products");
    $this->db->like("brand", $query);
    $this->db->or_like("model", $query);
    $this->db->limit($limit);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    // zero
    if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
        $output .= "No results found";
        return $output;
    }
    // result
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
        // uri
        $uri2 = "{$this->base_url}specifications/{$row['brand']}-{$row['model']}";
        $uri2 = str_replace(" ", "-", $uri2);
        // price format
        $row['price'] = number_format($row['price']);
        // image url
        $image = "{$this->base_url}assets/images/products/{$row['category']}-{$row['brand']}-{$row['model']}/thumb.png";
        $image = str_replace(" ", "-", $image);
        $output .= "<ul class=\"product\">\n
            <a href=\"{$uri2}\">\n
                <li class=\"product-image\"><img src=\"{$image}\" height=\"108\" width=\"57\" alt=\"\"></li>\n
                <li class=\"product-brand\">{$row['brand']}</li>\n
                <li class=\"product-model\">{$row['model']}</li>\n
                <li class=\"product-price\">{$row['price']} <span class=\"green\">pkr</span></li>\n
            </a>\n
        </ul>\n";
    }
    // return
    return $output;
}
```

Here I do three types of queries:

1- query that contains only brand (i get results)
2- query that contains only model (i get results)
3- query that contains both (i get no results)

How to accomplish the all above three tasks?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are performing some kind of search, so the there result that you want to get are coming from  controller or view, you jst do that make there if condition like this then do it as

```
if ($brand_val != '' )
{  //put your where query here }

if ($model_val  != '' )
{  //put your where query here }

if ($brand_val != '' && $model_val  != ''   )
{  //put your where query here }
```

hope this will give idea

Answer (score 0):

use this to print the query.

echo $this->db->last_query();

and then try execute that query in your phpmyadmin